# WebBrowser (VCL) Memory Leak Windows 2008r2

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, windows-server-2008-r2, twebbrowser

I have a form with a `TWebBrowser` dropped on it. When the form opens the following happens:

```
procedure TRouteMapView.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RouteMapView.Caption := 'Transport XLR - ' + Main.GlobalSite;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://****/map_only/' + TID);
end;
```

This loads a dynamic map for the optimized route. The problem is that if I close the form before the map is fully loaded the memory is not released. Even if I wait until it is fully loaded not all of the memory is released.

I tried following in `Formclose` without any success:

```
WebBrowser1.Stop;
WebBrowser1.Navigate('about::blank');
WebBrowser1.Free;
```

Strangely I am unable to reproduce the issue on Windows 10, **but** I have to support Windows 2008r2.

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried to Create the RouteMapView Form on Application Startup , and then just show and hide it as necessary . Unfortunately the "Leak" is still there and it's even worse . 
I've also tried to wait till the WebBrowser is done , once with ReadyState and once with Busy , it seems to do something . But I guess the damn Website is executing a lot of scripts in the Background and even though it says done it is not done .
I also thought about that maybe the Website itself is the culprit . So I changed it to www.microsoft.com ( I mean if that leaks then it does not matter :) ) , but it did leak .

So I started to think about writing a Small Application which does nothing but show the map and then just closes . And I call it as needed and wait for it.

And then I realized , when I close my Application Completely ... the Memory does gets Freed , since when I start another Program again everything is working fine , even if I reached the 1.5GB mark before .

**My knowledge is limited here , but is it possible to detect which instances of Internet Explorer were started by my Program and simply force terminate them ?**

Comment: Can you explain how you diagnose a memory leak

Comment: I've started TaskMgr on the Windows 2008r2 server and monitored how much RAM my program uses . It started with 80MB . Then I opened the form , and left it finish , it went to 82MB. Then I opened the form again but did not let it finish it went to 110MB ... did it again 130MB ... again 140MB ... again till I reached 180MB. This cannot be normal . Please note , the "normal" memory leak detection ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown does not see this is a leak... but the software is using more and more ram . And it is not freed until I completely close the program .

Comment: That's perfectly normal. You can't use task manager to diagnose memory leaks. Memory managers hold on to memory and then hope to re-use it. Nothing to see here. If you can add the information in that comment I can add an answer. Otherwise it may be best to close or just remove the post.

Comment: even if the Program goes to 500MB ? One day I was looking at the Memory usage and it was by 500MB . That scared me . That is still normal? But if the Program should ever reach the Limits of 32bit ... it will crash regardless no?

Comment: Can you produce a crash? Add some code on a timer to simulate the operations. See if you can make the program crash. If not then there is no problem.

Comment: unfortunately **yes**  . The Memory Usage goes to 1.575.194 MB approx . The Program itself does not get a OUT of Memory Error . But I do get an ERROR from the Webbrowser itself (though in German) but it roughly translates Not Enough Memory to Display Page -1 .

Comment: Can you notice the same memory usage increase even if you just create your form without navigating your browser to any page? Also have you considered not to create your form every time but instead create it once and then simply hide it when it is not used?

Comment: OK, so this would seem to suggest that it really is a leak. The issue is in the underlying Web browser control. Probably all you can do is wait for the page to complete loading before closing the form. Or just accept the leak on this OS. I'd expect the same leak on Windows 7.

Comment: Has the W2008R2 system been patched with the latest updates? There were quite a few "memory leak" issues that have been reported on this OS...

Answer (score 0):

I created here a Small Program which does nothing but process parameters from my Main Application and Displays the Result in the Web-browser .

As far as I can tell I have no more Memory Leaking .

What I noticed with the External Program is , that sometimes when I called it I've received a error something about fwpuclnt.dll and sometimes dhcpcsv6.dll .

I was doing the Navigation on the Form.OnShow , so I switched instead to a Timer ,
when the Program is started I wait 2 seconds then I try to navigate . The Errors regarding the two dll's are gone now . I only receive sometimes an error from Internet Explorer itself , cannot navigate to page , click refresh . Otherwise it is fine.

Oh and I forgot to mention this is a Windows 2008r2 Terminal Server .

Regards
Robert